# Programatically edit Helm templates?

Tags: python, yaml, kubernetes-helm

Let's say I have a large set of Helm charts, in which I want to edit every `deployment.yaml` file in the `templates` directory of each chart, which doing manually is a tedious task.

I've tried to use Python's `pyyaml` and `benedict` to do something like this:

```
content = read_file() # reads the deployment.yaml file
deployment = yaml.unsafe_load(content)
deployment = benedict(deployment)
```

But I get this:

```
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a flow node
expected the node content, but found '-'
  in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 4:
     {{- include "something.labels" ...
```

I suppose that since the `deployment.yaml` which is a Helm template is not a valid YAML, pyyaml can't decode it.

Does anyone know another way?

Comment: can you please add an example YAML template

Answer (score 0):

Helm templates are just [Go templates](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template). The work on text. You can, theoretically, parse them into a syntax tree representing the Go template syntax, but that's not what you want.

Only after template processing will the input become a valid YAML structure. Therefore, you generally cannot make code comprehend the structure of both Go templates and the resulting YAML at the same time, which you'd need to be able to modify the original file in a structure-aware way.

<sub>Give me [a research team and five years](https://xkcd.com/1425/) and I might be able to do it…</sub>

Since it's not realistically possible to do it structurally, just do what everyone does and use `sed` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jinja2 a simple example would be:

*templates/deployment.yaml.j2*

```
apiVersion: {{ spec.api_version }}
kind: Deployment
metadata:
{% for m in spec.metadata %}
  {{ m | indent(2, true) }}
{% endfor %}
spec:
  containers:
  - image: {{ spec.image }}
```

*script.py*

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

spec = {
  "image": "nginx:1.23.2",
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
  "metadata": ["name: nginx"]
}

def get_template(__file):
  j2 = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(searchPath="templates")).get_template(__file)
  return template = j2.render(spec=spec)

def generate_template(__target_file, template):
  with open(__target_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(template)

# could loop through multiple deployment.yaml.j2 files
template = get_template("deployment.yaml.j2")
generate_template("my_chart/templates/deployment.yaml", template)
```

The trade-off here is that you will have a set of templates that jinja/python will manipulate and then generate static templates for your charts.

Maybe there's better alternatives, but I decided to share an approach I took for something similar. Of course this example is very simple and would be better solved with just using a values file, but the idea is that you can expand on it from there and template the files as you see fit.